# Is there a callback function when UIView's frame change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

Suppose that I need to do something **whenever** a view's width or height changes. When not using autoLayout, I can do this by implementing `layoutSubviews`. But I find that this function is not always called when using autoLayout.

Right now, I'm using the following code where something could possibly cause the view's frame to change:

```
[self setNeedsLayout];
[self layoutIfNeeded];
```

and do what I must do in `layoutSubviews`. But I wonder if this is the best way. Is there a simpler solution, for example a callback function I can use?

Comment: width and height of a view would change when you update the constraints in your code. And after updating constraints you need to call `layoutIfNeeded` which in turn will result in `layoutSubviews` being called, so I think you are doing fine with your existing approach.

Comment: I feel a lot more confident now. Thank you @uchiha :)

Comment: maybe you can set a property observer up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have to call both methods at once. Calling `setNeedsLayout` schedules the view for layouting at the next layouting run, you don't know when this will happen.

On the other hand, `layoutIfNeeded` layouts the view and all it's subviews immediately. Then `layoutSubviews` should be called for all the views in the hierarchy starting with the one on which you called `layoutIfNeeded`.

If you changed your constraints and you need to update your view you should call layoutIfNeeded probably in an animation block so that the views don't "jump", using something like this

```
// Update constraints ...

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    [view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

If you don't change your frame "by hand" (meaning using `setFrame:`) and update your view only through constraints, after which you call `layoutIfNeeded`, `layoutSubviews` should be called every time.

If you do use `setFrame:`, which you should not do if you are using auto layout, then you can try using an observer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for a callback. Apple's documentation says

> Called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out
>   its subviews.

Have a closer look here: https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html

Happy coding!
Z.

**Update:**

I've answered the wrong question before! :)
For `UIView`s you can override `bounds`' setter `setBounds` (not `frame`/`setFrame`, that's a value derived from `bounds`), and in there you'll get notified of any size change.
Don't forget to call `[super setBounds:bounds]` in your implementation :)

Z.

Comment: Thanks pallzoltan! I have heard about that method, but unfortunately it is a method of UIViewController, and I need a similar one of UIView :(

Comment: Ah okay, sorry, I've mixed the question with another one, probably :) I've updated my answer ;)

Comment: strangely I have found a case that the view changes size again after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called the last time. I am starting to suspect that at the time `viewDidLayoutSubviews` runs it means that a series of layouts will happen and something is about to change to new sizes and positions but these values are not known yet.

Comment: 2 things: 
1) You're talking about `UIViewController`s, the question is about `UIView`s.
2) I wonder what view hierarchy you have set up (Custom `UIViews` as children, etc), and I think even the system can ask sometimes for multiple layouts to happen.